# Pass Javascript variable to TYPO3 variable

Tags: javascript, typo3, fluid

With the following JS I get the height of a div

```
    document.addEventListener(
        "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
          const element = document.getElementById("c27");
          let text = element.offsetHeight + "px";
          document.getElementsByTagName("divSize").??? = text;
        }

    );
```

Now I want to pass the variable to a fluid variable as value

```
<f:variable name="divSize" value="???" />
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Fluid is rendered server side. JavaScript is run client side. `<f:variable name="divSize" value="???" />` does not exist client side.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do an `HTTP request` either by reloading the page and adding a `URL parameter` or by pushing the value to the server via `AJAX` and providing the value as a parameter. Then you can handle the value within that request via `Fluid` and return either a full page or a an `HTML-snippet`.

Answer (score -2):

```
document.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      const element = document.getElementById("c27");
      let text = element.offsetHeight + "px";
      document.querySelector("[name=divSize]").setAttribute('value', text);
    }
);
```

`document.getElementsByTagName("divSize")` looks for `<divSize>` elements, not `name="divSize"`. You can use `document.getElememtsByName()`, but `document.querySelector()` is a little simpler (it just returns the first match, so you don't have to index it).

Use `setAttribute()` to set the `value` attribute. You might be able to assign to the `.value` property, but that normally only exists for user input elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`). I don't know whether `<f:variable>` supports this property directly.